# c# console add or subtract calculator

Tags: c#

I am a c# beginner so I have a problem in my c# console calculator here is the code

```
Console.WriteLine("If you want to add click 1 , subtract click 2");
int userchoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if (userchoice == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
    int firstinput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter another number");
    int secondinput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Click =");
    string choice = Console.ReadLine();
    if (choice == "=")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(firstinput + secondinput);
    }
    else  if (userchoice == 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
        int firstinput1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter another number");
        int secondinput1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Click =");
        string choice2 = Console.ReadLine();
        if (choice2 == "=")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(firstinput1 - secondinput1);
        }
```

The problem is if I entered 1 it will make the addition operation but if I entered 2 it won't do anything why although I am writing its code as what is right answer.

Comment: Your missing a brace before the `else` - what editor are you using to write your code? Most editors nowadays will alert you to the fact that something is syntactically wrong

Comment: I edited your question and fixed the indentation (taking the braces as originally posted). The fixed indentation shows cleary that you missed a closing brace before `else if (userchoice == 2)`

Comment: Most of that code shouldn't even be in the `if` and `else if` since they are identical.  Try to only put the code that is different into `if` statements.

Comment: Btw, you could simplify your code: let the user always input the two numbers and then let him specify if he wants to add or subtract both. Both actions require two numbers. Then the remaing `if` is pretty trivial: `if(userchoice == 1) result = firstinput + secondinput; else if(userchoice == 2) result = firstinput - secondinput;`

Answer (score 0):

you have mixed the else statements. Right now your `else  if (userchoice == 2)` matches statement  `if (choice == "=")`. Try:

```
if (userchoice == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
    int firstinput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter another number");
    int secondinput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Click =");
    string choice = Console.ReadLine();
    if (choice == "=")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(firstinput + secondinput);
    }
}
else if (userchoice == 2)
{
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
        int firstinput1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter another number");
        int secondinput1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Click =");
        string choice2 = Console.ReadLine();
        if (choice2 == "=")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(firstinput1 - secondinput1);
        }
 }
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("Wrong Selection, either select 1 or 2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@FatmaHamdy , You missed the } before the else part

```
Console.WriteLine("If you want to add click 1 , subtract click 2");
int userchoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if (userchoice == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
    int firstinput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter another number");
    int secondinput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Click =");
    string choice = Console.ReadLine();
    if (choice == "=")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(firstinput + secondinput);
    }
}
    else  if (userchoice == 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
        int firstinput1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter another number");
        int secondinput1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Click =");
        string choice2 = Console.ReadLine();
        if (choice2 == "=")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(firstinput1 - secondinput1);
        }
}
```